# Can I write code to en/decrypt TLSv1.2 packets?

Tags: encryption, https, network-programming, wireshark

I am interested in the bit-level goings-on of computer networks, and have been using Wireshark to look at outgoing packets my computer sends when I send messages into the message box of a text-based game, which is hosted on an external web server.

Every time I post a message, I can see a TLSv1.2 packet is sent out, the payload of which is encrypted.  My question is how would I go about encrypting outgoing packets myself (using C++)?

My only thoughts on this are that, since encryption happens locally and probably inside my web browser process, I might be able to send a message, note the encrypted output, and then use a time-travel debugger to look inside the process memory, watch for when memory was set to whatever was sent out, then go backwards in the assembly code to try to work out what it's doing.  I think there is probably a better way.

Equally, when the server sends messages back, how could I use code to decode those?

I am aware my browser has been given a cookie which looks like a private key, would the process use this cookie for encrypting and decrypting, or is that a red herring?

Comment: Of course you can write it yourself. Somebody did. If you start now you should be finished by about December 2022.

Comment: I'm writing TLS 1.3 and although I could finish sooner it seems 1 Dec. 2022 is a good deadline (I'm pretty sure I could finish it in a week if I really focused, as my handshake is already accepted) :P. I might have a bit of an advantage when it comes to understanding encoding and crypto though - like 20 years of practice. Anyway, to implement TLS 1.2 or 1.3 **you try and read the standard**. If you cannot do that directly, then you probably are best off buying a some text in dead tree format about this subject (i.e. a book). Or start with something easier.

Comment: And @MaartenBodewes has no doubt already implemented 50-100 cipher suites and is presumably only now implementing the difference between TLS 1.3 and its predecessors. Start by reading RFC 2246 and successors, and get Eric Rescoria's excellent TLS book.

Comment: Why don't you simply redirect the traffic through an HTTPS decrypting proxy like Fiddler, Zap, Burp, Charles, ... You only have to trust the root CA certificate of the used proxy in your OS or your C++ program.

Comment: @Robert He wants to 'encrypt outgoing packets [him]self'. Not *decrypt* packets. Read the question.